# Proving $\frac{1}{a+2}+\frac{1}{b+2}+\frac{1}{c+2}\leq 1$ for positive $a$, $b$, $c$ with $abc=1$with AM-GM

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> If $a,b,c>0$ and $abc=1$, prove
> $$\frac{1}{a+2}+\frac{1}{b+2}+\frac{1}{c+2}\leq 1$$

I replaced x=1/a y=1/b z=1/c and x/(2x+1)+y/(2y+1)+z/(2z+1) <=1 but can't seem to get further than that. How should I use AM-GM inequality here?

Comment: [You asked this question already](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4748287/409), and it was closed by the community for lacking details. Re-posting is not the appropriate way to circumvent closure; rather, you should edit the original to improve its quality in hopes of attracting re-open votes. (You can request re-open votes [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34447/409).) ... Also, take a closer look at the formatting I did on your mathematical expressions so that you can do the same. (See this [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/409).) ... Good luck!